# is regretting and regrets

Tags: word-usage, tense

I know this is the basic grammar knowledge, but I can't figure out the differences between these sentences:

1)We sure hope Brad ***is regretting*** those hateful tweets now.

and

2)We sure hope Brad ***regrets*** those hateful tweets now.

***Is regretting*** an ongoing and continuous feeling?? And ***Regret*** is just present feeling, not future??

And does it matter if I use on and not the other??

Comment: The continuous form puts emphasis on Brad experiencing that regret (right now, in this case). There's a sense of him going through something, feeling that regret. You'll see this construction a lot when people want to put the emphasis on that experience, e.g. *I hope you're enjoying yourself!*

Answer (score 0):

***to regret*** refers to a mental state, (although I have also found it classified as ***a verb of emotion*** on [the grammar exchange](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/stative-verbs-in-the-progressive-form#:%7E:text=Verbs%20of%20emotion%3A%20abhor%2C%20adore,remember%2C%20think%2C%20and%20understand.)) and if you check [the poligo site](https://poligo.com/en/articles/grammar/mental-states-and-present-continuous-recent-change-thinking), you will find that:

> Use the present continuous with verbs about mental states and emotions
> to show ***a new way of thinking*** or ***that we are not sure***. Words that are
> used to talk about mental states are usually used in the present
> simple. These are words like ***find, realise, regret, think, understand,
> hope*** etc.

> However, we can use the present continuous to show that we have had a recent change in our thinking, that we are starting to think a new way about something or that we are unsure about something.

Compare:

> - I regret being so careless.

and

> - I am regretting my decision to change jobs.

The same site goes on to explain that

`In sentence (1), I was careless and made a mistake. It has happened and I feel very terrible about it. I will probably feel bad whenever I think about it.`

`In sentence (2), I made a decision and at the time, I thought it was a good idea. However, as time passes, I am starting to feel more and more like it was a bad decision. I think I should not have done that.`

In [***Advanced Grammar in Use***](http://144.122.235.170/ckfinder/userfiles/files/Advanced%20Grammar%20in%20Use%202nd%20Edition.pdf) I found this example:

> ***I’m regretting*** my decision to give her the job.

In this example, the verb ***regret*** is used in the progressive aspect in order to enhance the fact that the speaker has started to feel sorry about his/her decision in giving the job. The textbook indicates that ***regret*** was used in the progressive form to indicate that the speaker is “increasingly aware that it was the wrong decision”.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, they're broadly the same. But there is a very fine distinction between them.

*`"is regretting"`* form implies *a feeling*, or let's say *a longing*, that's growing increasingly, whereas *`"regret(s)"`* is a one-time period. Both of which are happing now even if you omit the adverb, "now."

Back to your question, it doesn't *really* matter when you use either - but keep in mind what you want to express.
The "is regretting" example sounds more emotional.

I agree "is regretting" is continuous and "regret" is the present time and not the future. As I said, both are referring to the here and now - there is no future meaning.

> Talking about the future - *you **'re gonna** regret... or  you **'ll** regret...*